# How can I change the outmost tag of bare XML in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-serialization

I have a web service using WebInvoke, and I'd like to change the tags that are being returned.

The current service looks like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
               Method = "GET",
               RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
               UriTemplate = "/")]
    List<DataObject> getCurrentData();
```

And it returns XML that looks like this:

```
  <ArrayOfDataObject xmlns="...">
    <DataObject>
       ...
    </DataObject>
    ...
  </ArrayOfDataObject>
```

Using WCF, how can I change the tags that are being emitted as <ArrayOfDataObject> and <DataObject> to something more general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Maess for putting me on the right track. Here's what I ended up with:

```
    [CollectionDataContract(ItemName="element", Name = "elementCollection")]
    public class DataResponse<T> : List<T>
    {
        public DataResponse() : base()
        {
        }

        public DataResponse(List<T> list) : base()
        {
            this.AddRange(list);        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use serialization hints in `DataObject` itself.  These will inform the serializer how to render the objects and its properties.

```
[XmlRoot("YourNewNameHere")]
public class DataObject
{
}
```

Comment: It looks like the XML serialization hints work for attributes inside of DataObject, but I can't figure out how they apply to the &lt;DataObject> tag itself.

Comment: Thank you for that, but it seems like WCF routes around the standard XML serialization hinting. I had to use a CollectionDataContract to do this.